# How to iterate through rows which contains text and create bigrams using python

Tags: python, pandas

In an excel file I have 5 columns and 20 rows, out of which one row contains text data as shown below
`df['Content']` row contains:

```
0 this is the final call
1 hello how are you doing 
2 this is me please say hi
..
.. and so on
```

I want to create bigrams while it remains attached to its original table.

I tried applying the below function to iterate through rows

```
def find_bigrams(input_list):
    bigram_list = []
    for i in range(len(input_list)-1):
        bigram_list.append(input_list[1:])
        return bigram_list
```

And tried applying back the row into its table using the:

```
df['Content'] = df['Content'].apply(find_bigrams)
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
0     None
1     None
2     None
```

I am expecting the output as below

```
   Company  Code      Content
0  xyz      uh-11     (this,is),(is,the),(the,final),(final,call)
1  abc      yh-21     (hello,how),(how,are),(are,you),(you,doing)
```

Comment: Where are Company & Code supposed to be coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `input_list` is not actually a list, it's a string.

Try the function below:

```py
def find_bigrams(input_text):
    input_list = input_text.split(" ")
    bigram_list = list(map(tuple, zip(input_list[:-1], input_list[1:])))
    return bigram_list
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine. But also how do I get it in this format

                                                                                     [(this, is), (is, the),(the,final),(final,call)]
                      [(hello,how),(how,are),(are,you),(you,doing)]

Comment: updated answer to match the expected output format

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thanks
Is there a universal code that I can use to change between unigram,bigram and trigram?

   input_list = list(ngrams(tokens,2)) 
where i can change the number to 3 to obtain trigram

Comment: There's the [ngram](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/model/ngram.html) module in `numpy`. Also, do consider upvoting the answer if it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.permutations()`

```
s.str.split().map(lambda x: list(itertools.permutations(x,2))[::len(x)])
```

or `itertools.pairwise()`

```
s.str.split().map(lambda x: list(itertools.pairwise(x)))
```